# Como compartilhar uma imagem (ImageView) usando Intent?

Tags: java, android, imagem, intent

Estou tendo uma grande dificuldade em compartilhar uma imagem de uma ImageView a partir de um botão, tentei vários métodos, mas nenhum funcionou.

Segue um exemplo do que estou querendo compartilhar:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/l0b5eobtpdbeoen/Screenshot_20170509-135902.png

Possuo um array com o caminho das imagens no Drawable

```
final int[] photos = {
                R.drawable.abrir_a_boca,
                R.drawable.adicao_de_quartos,
                R.drawable.agarrado_firmemente,
                R.drawable.agradeca,
                R.drawable.alfaiate,
                R.drawable.ancora,
}

compartilhar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                shareImage();
            }

            private void shareImage() {

                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "local do arquivo");
                shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                startActivity(shareIntent);
            }
```

mas nunca funcionou, agora não sei se o problema é o meu aparelho que está com Cyanogen, pois já vi diversas soluções para este problema no Stackoverflow, mas nenhum funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário salvar a imagem, para que se possa compartilhar:

Vamos lá:

> 1. Permissão:

Em seu arquivo **AndroidManifest.xml** adicione a permissão para que possamos salvar a imagem no dispositivo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

> 2. Permissões em tempo de execução:

A partir do Android 6.0 (nível de API 23), os usuários concedem permissões a aplicativos enquanto eles estão em execução, não quando eles são instalados.

Para isso adicione o seguinte método de código:

```
private static final int SOLICITAR_PERMISSAO = 1;
private void checarPermissao(){

    // Verifica  o estado da permissão de WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Se for diferente de PERMISSION_GRANTED, então vamos exibir a tela padrão 
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, SOLICITAR_PERMISSAO);
    } else {
        // Senão vamos compartilhar a imagem
        sharedImage();
    }
}
```

> 3. Compartilhar a imagem:

Agora, vamos salvar e compartilhar a imagem:

```
   private void sharedImage(){
        // Vamos carregar a imagem em um bitmap
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //setamos o tipo da imagem
        share.setType("image/jpeg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // comprimomos a imagem
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        // Gravamos a imagem
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Titulo da Imagem", null);
        // criamos uam Uri com o endereço que a imagem foi salva
        Uri imageUri =  Uri.parse(path);
        // Setmaos a Uri da imagem
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        // chama o compartilhamento
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Selecione"));
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e pelo belo tutorial, já irei testa-lo.

Comment: Olá, Thiago.
Nessa linha  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, SOLICITAR_PERMISSAO);

o que seria esse SOLICITAR PERMISSÃO?

Pois não conseguiu resolver esse parâmetro.

Obrigado.

Comment: Thiago, nem sei como te agradecer.
Perfeito, funcionou suavemente o código.
Muito bom.
Estou quase uma semana agarrado com esse problema e testei diversos métodos e nenhum havia funcionado.
Obrigado pela contribuição e por compartilhar seu conhecimento.
Valeu demais.
Abraço.